# $_session value counter

Tags: php, session, counter

I have a quiz where by results are sent using session like this to result.php page

```
    {
        $_SESSION['result'] = 'Correct Answer!';
    }else{
        $_SESSION['result'] = 'Wrong Answer!';
    }
```

on the session.php page i would like a counter which counts all 'correct answer!' and 'wrong answer!' . eventually im also trying to figure the arithmetic to display a percentage of correct and wrong results and overall score based on this counter..

any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

Counters initialization (may be performed every time before stepping):

```
if(!isset($_SESSION['correctAnswers'])
    $_SESSION['correctAnswers'] = 0;
if(!isset($_SESSION['wrongAnswers'])
    $_SESSION['wrongAnswers'] = 0;
```

Counters stepping:

```
if(...) {
    $_SESSION['result'] = 'Correct Answer!';
    $_SESSION['correctAnswers'] += 1;
}else{
    $_SESSION['result'] = 'Wrong Answer!';
    $_SESSION['wrongAnswers'] += 1;
}
```

Score:

```
$correctAnswers = $_SESSION['correctAnswers'];
$totalAnswers = $_SESSION['wrongAnswers'] + $correctAnswers;
if($totalAnswers > 0)
    $score = $correctAnswers / ($totalAnswers) * 100;
else 
    $score = 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

Isn't this just a simple case of wanting to store the number of questions answered and the number of questions answered correctly?

If so the the percentage of correct answers is `($correctCount / $totalCount) * 100`